# Novel with the plague and a knight sent from the devil

Tags: story-identification, novel

I’ve been reading a novel, and I want to see if you know what novel I'm talking about.

There are people that need to go to Nebraska to find an old woman, and they need to fight a knight sent from devil.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not actually a question; it seems more like you're playing a "guess what I'm reading" game with us.

Comment: See https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/223396/miniseries-in-post-rapture-us-with-good-evil-conflict for additional information about this novel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're referring to Stephen King's [The Stand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stand).

- There's a plague
- The main protagonists travel to Hemingford Home, Nebraska to meet an old woman
- The main antagonist is a servant of the devil.

Comment: Did I give this to much detail

Comment: Yes, far too much. Try harder next time. "Uh,  there's this book about a guy named Jesus. I remember it was a good book"...

Comment: @Richard: [Lamb](http://www.amazon.com/Lamb-Gospel-According-Christs-Childhood/dp/0380813815)?

Comment: @Voldemort - Bwing me Bwian!